# Таймер обратного отсчета в секундах с перезагрузкой

Tags: html, jquery

Есть такой код: https://codepen.io/zikwal/pen/NWGodpV (Для воспроизведения)

**UPDATE:** Ответ ниже - как видно - работает и выполняет именно то, что нужно, но он написан не по моему коду - и не получается его к моему адаптировать. *(Если, кто может в этом помочь - буду благодарен)*

**ВОПРОС:**
HTML Выводится из БД через PHP, для примера запечатал HTML.
Суть в том, что при нажатии на чекбокс - меняется вопрос. Необходимо ограничить время ответа и в случае отсутствия ответа через 15 сек - сделать выбор за пользователя.
Реализовал таймер обратного отсчета но не могу реализовать к нему оставшиеся две функции:
**1 -** Чтобы при достижении 0 автоматически выбирался 2 ответ
**2 -** Чтобы при нажатии на чекбокс - таймер перезагружался

*(Перекопал много постов, пытался через if else, addClass/removeClass - но реализовать так и не смог - надеюсь на помощь и хоть небольшое разъяснение)*

*Развёрнутый код:*

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="test-data">
    <div class="question" data-id="6" id="question-6">

        <p class="q">Вопрос 1</p>
        <p class="a">
            <input type="radio" id="answer-1" name="question-6" value="1">
            <label for="answer-1">1</label>
        </p>
        <p class="a">
            <input type="radio" id="answer-2" name="question-6" value="2">
            <label for="answer-2">2</label>
        </p>
      <div class="sec seconds">15</div>
    </div>
    <div class="question" data-id="4" id="question-4">

        <p class="q">Вопрос 2</p>
        <p class="a">
            <input type="radio" id="answer-1" name="question-4" value="1">
            <label for="answer-1">1</label>
        </p>
        <p class="a">
            <input type="radio" id="answer-2" name="question-4" value="2">
            <label for="answer-2">2</label>
        </p>
      <div class="sec">15</div>
    </div>
    <div class="question" data-id="5" id="question-5">
        <p class="q">Вопрос 3</p>
        <p class="a">
            <input type="radio" id="answer-1" name="question-5" value="1">
            <label for="answer-1">1</label>
        </p>
        <p class="a">
            <input type="radio" id="answer-2" name="question-5" value="2">
            <label for="answer-2">2</label>
        </p>
      <div class="sec">15</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.q{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.a {
    padding: 5px 0;
}
.question {
    display: none;
}
.nav-active {
    display: none;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$('.test-data').children('div:first').show();
$('input[id^="answer"]').click(({currentTarget})=>{
    $(currentTarget).parent().parent().hide().next().fadeIn();
    console.log($(currentTarget).attr('name'), $(currentTarget).val());
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var sec = $('.seconds');
  var secVal = parseInt(sec.text());

  var timer = setTimeout(function tick() {
    if (secVal > 0) {
      sec.text(--secVal);
      timer = setTimeout(tick, 1000);
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

id элементов по определению должны быть уникальными на странице...

Легче редактировать данные в JS, чем дублировать HTML. Было бы удобнее оформить это в таком виде:

```js
var data = [
  {
    question: "Вопрос-1",
    answers: ["Вариант-1", "Вариант-2"],
  },
  {
    question: "Вопрос-2",
    answers: ["100500", "500100"],
  },
  {
    question: "Вопрос-3",
    answers: ["bubu", "moo", "doo"],
  },
];

/***/

var $test = $('.test-data');
var timerFrom = 15;
var index = -1;
var timeout = null;

nextQuestion();

$test.on('change', 'input[type="radio"]', function() {
  logAnswer( $(this) );
  nextQuestion();
});

/***/
function setHTML(index) {
  var obj = data[index];
  
  var html = '<p class="question">' + obj.question + '</p>';
  for( var i = 0; i < obj.answers.length; i++ ) {
    html += (    
      '<p class="answer">' +
        '<label><input type="radio" name="question" value="' + i + '"><span>' +
          obj.answers[i] +
        '</span></label>' +
      '</p>'
    );
  }
  
  html += '<div class="sec">' + timerFrom + '</div>';
  
  $test.html( html );
}

function nextQuestion() {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  $test.fadeOut(500);
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    index++;
    if( !data[index] ) return console.log("Вопросы закончились");
    
    setHTML(index);    
    runTimer();
    $test.fadeIn();
  }, 500);
}

function runTimer() {
  var sec = $('.test-data .sec');
  var seconds = timerFrom;
  
  loop();
  function loop() {
    sec.text( seconds );
    if( seconds <= 0 ) {
      autoAnswer();
      nextQuestion();
      return;
    }
    
    seconds--;
    timeout = setTimeout(loop, 1000);
  }
}

function autoAnswer() {
  var answers = data[index].answers;
  var $radio = $('.test-data .answer input').eq( answers.length - 1 );
  $radio.prop("checked", true);  
  logAnswer( $radio );
}

function logAnswer($elem) {
  console.log( "Номер: " + $elem.val() + ", Значение: " + $elem.next('span').text() );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="test-data"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Вопросы выводятся с помощью PHP из БД - Просто рабочий пример на HTML сделал без SQL

Comment: К сожалению не получилось его адаптировать под свой код - как не "колдовал". Не могли бы Вы помочь переделать свой код - чтобы он заработал на моём примере?

Comment: @ZikWal https://jsfiddle.net/142sn8hg/1/ - допустим. Выкинул только одинаковые id из верстки и все инпуты завернул в label.